# Proper way to use json_encoded form data to create dynamic insert statements

Tags: php, angular, ionic4

I have several tables with many columns that will be populated from form data the user inputs in PHP.  Instead of having to put each column name and value individually, `INSERT INTO`users`(`email`,`password`) VALUES ('$email','$password')` is there a way to correctly do this using the json encoded data so with the more complex tables so I don't need to do:

```
INSERT INTO `profile`(`user_id`, `fName`, `lName`, `address1`, 
                    `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `phone`, 
                    `country`, `dob`, `homeBase`, `active`) 
            VALUES ('$user[id]','$fName', '$lName', '$address1', 
                    '$address2', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$phone', 
                    '$country', '$dob', '$homeBase', 'active')`
```

where all the info comes from:

```
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->email));
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->password));
  $fName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->fName));
  $lName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->lName));
  $address1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->address1));
  $address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->address2));
  $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->city));
  $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->state));
  $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->zip));
  $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->phone));
  $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->country));
  $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->dob));
  $homeBase = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($request->data->homeBase));
```

I am using Angular and Ionic to create the form and get the data, if that makes a difference to anyone.  Everything works as is, just looking for a better way as the tables and forms grow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ___You do need a better way___ Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: @RiggsFolly this question has nothing to do with SQL injection.  I am only posting the parts of the code that I felt were relevant.  I have my security in place, this was asking for a better way to formulate the query to I was not assigning values for every column.  Please re-open this as it was closed incorrectly!

Comment: If you are using that code, you do NOT have your security in place

Comment: "Instead of having to put each column name and value individually"...that's how you write SQL statements. There isn't a shortcut. (Well, technically you can leave out the column names, but that's well known as a bad practice, likely to cause maintenance / debugging / readability headaches later on). You could use the list in $request->data to try and auto-generate the SQL statement, but unless you know you'll always be inserting to all fields in your table, it could leave you vulnerable to over-posting attacks potentially. You'd have to validate carefully, which is always request-specific.

Comment: If you want to write code to take some JSON and formulate a query out of it, thats fine, but there is no `magic_json_to_query()` function call if thats what you are asking

Comment: And the SQL injection comments above are perfectly relevant, IMHO. Security is always relevant.